# JQuery tr:not to skip 2 trs with class names

Tags: jquery

I want to skip 2 tr in the table with 2 different classes.

first tr with class is .gridTitleRow and 2nd tr with class is .gridSpan . How to skip these in below syntax?

```
$.each($(".gridTable tr:not(.gridTitleRow)"), function(a, b){});
```

**EDITED** I am using each like below

```
$("#gridBtn").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var indexArraay = [];
     var flag = false;
     $.each($(".gridTable tr:not(.gridTitleRow)"), function(a, b){

            var id = $("input.idField", b).val();
            var order = $("input[id='index']", b).val();
            var active = $("input[id='activeCb']", b).attr("checked");
            var deleteRow = $("input[id='deleteCb']", b).attr("checked");

            (deleteRow == true) ? flag = true : null;

            indexArraay.push({
                "id": id,
                "index": order,
                "active": active,
                "delete": deleteRow
            })
     });

    if (flag == true)
    {
        $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

        var text = "Alert: Deleting footer Prent menu will delete all submenus and assigned pages to it.";
        $('<div title="Confirmation:">' + text + '</div>').dialog({
            height: 'auto',
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Confirm: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    ProcessGrid(indexArraay);
                    ReloadGrid();
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        ProcessGrid(indexArraay);
        //ReloadGrid();
    }

}); //End of gridBtn
```

**Table**

```
<script id="gridTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td class="gridSpan" colspan="5">${$data[0].Title}</td>
    </tr>
    {{tmpl($data) "#cellTemplate"}}
</script>
<script id="cellTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td class="cellTd ">
            <input type="checkbox" id="deleteCb" />
            <input type="hidden" id="Id_ + ${num}" class="idField" value="${Id}" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">
            <input id="index" name="index" class="numberField" type="text" value="${IndexOrder}" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">${DisplayName}</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">${UrlName}</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">
            <input type="checkbox" id="activeCb" {{if Active}} checked{{/if}} />
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>   

<span class="instructions">Only numeric value is allowed in IndexOrder textbox.</span>
<div class="gridDiv">
<table class="gridTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gridTitleRow">
            <td class="iconLink width36">Delete</td>
            <td class="iconLink width60">Sort Order</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Display Name</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Url Name</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Active</td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can't you simply add `not(.gridTitleRow, .gridSpan)`?

Comment: seems like I was giving you a jumpstart and it was kind of right ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.each($(".gridTable tr:not(.gridTitleRow, .gridSpan)"), function(a, b){});
```

In selectors, the "," is like "or".  <strike>Wait - it's like "and", but because your selector here is in a "not()" clause, it's "not this one and not that one", which is like "not (this one or that one)".</strike>  I think I may belabor the point a bit :-)

*edit* — no I convinced myself it's "or" again.  Need coffee.

*edit again* — a couple things:

- There's no reason to call "$.each()" when the first object is already a jQuery object:

  ```
  $(".gridTable tr:not(.gridTitleRow, .gridSpan)").each(function(i, elem) {
  ```
- When searching by "id" value, there's no reason to use an attribute selector, and there's no reason to use a context because "id" values **must be unique**.  Use "#id":

  ```
  var order = $('#index');
  ```
- Please note again that it is **invalid** to use the same "id" value for multiple elements on a page. If you're using the same "id" on many table rows, that is wrong and you'll have to change it.
- The jQuery team has deprecated the form `$(selector, base)` and prefer the form `$(base).find(selector)`.  Internally, the library always performs that transformation, so you might as well save it the trouble:

  ```
  var deleteRow = $(b).find('#deleteCb');
  ```
- It's not at all clear what "flag" is supposed to do, but you may have forgotten to declare it. Maybe it's a global variable.
- Your comment says that "empty tr is passing with undefined", but I do not know what that means. If the selector finds no `<tr>` elements, the "each" loop will simply not happen.  If you describe what exactly it is that's undefined, it might be possible to help.

Comment: I have edited my question and added more detail. Hope everything will be clear. Please let me if I can improve it

Comment: That's good news on the deprecation of the hideous `$(selector, base)`. Could you point me to a reference? I don't see it in the docs or release notes.

Comment: I've heard Paul Irish say it at a couple of conferences. I don't know whether that counts :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably take it out of the selector so that you retain your valid `querySelectorAll` selector:

```
$(".gridTable tr").not('.gridTitleRow,.gridSpan').each( function(a, b){});
```

The selector would be valid for `qsa` if there was only one class name you were filtering out using `:not()`, but with two, it becomes invalid, and defaults to the Sizzle's javascript based engine.

Comment: Yes this is probably a really good idea, particularly on a big (in terms of DOM nodes) page.  (And pages with tables tend to be naturally big.)

Comment: Your solution not working. Empty tr is passing. I have added more info in my question.

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, and I'm on a personal quest to proselytize people away from proprietary selectors, one SO question at a time. ;o)

Comment: The only way I know anything about all those fancy selector things is from questions here; I basically never use them :-)